# Determining if checkbox is checked in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, checkbox, ionic2

How can I determine if a ion-checkbox is checked in Ionic 2.

```
   <ion-item *ngFor="let a of q.Answers">
      <ion-label>{{a.AnswerDescription}}</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox (click)="addValue($event)"></ion-checkbox>
   </ion-item>
```

the following return `undefined`

```
 addValue(e): void {
     var isChecked = e.currentTarget.checked;
     console.log(isChecked);//undefined

 }
```

Comment: you should check if `a.checked` is `true`, since it's the model ytou binded to the input.

Comment: With normal HTML checkbox it works. But I'm not sure with `ion control`.

Comment: Has each element of the `Answers` array a property called `checked`?

Comment: No, I tried something. I edited the post and removed ngModel.

Comment: Would it be a valid option, to add a boolean property (maybe something like `selected`) to each `Answers` element? I guess that would be the easiest way to know (not only in the click event) if an answer was checked or not... If that's a valid option, I can write an answer explaining how to do it.

Comment: If possible that would be helpful, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use an NgModel

```
<ion-checkbox checked="false" [(ngModel)]="yourVariable.checked"></ion-checkbox>
```

Comment: I like this method more. It is more stable, on updates, some event listeners may change. Model is more stable

Answer (score 25):

Use e.checked property if you really wanted to pass $event as an argument as shown below.

**HTML**

```
<ion-checkbox color="dark" checked="true" (ionChange)="datachanged($event)" ></ion-checkbox>
```

**TYPESCRIPT**

```
datachanged(e:any){
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.checked);
}
```

Comment: In Ionic 3 it just worked when I replaced "(ionChange)" by "(click)"